# The bottom of Webview content inside a fragment using Tabbed Activity is cut off

Tags: java, android

I am stuck here, I used a Textview previously but the content is cut off at the bottom so I tried using a webview to display the contents inside a fragment using a Tabbed Activity which is my current view. This is the current output using a Tablet :
[Current](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iayO8.png)

[image]

This is my xml code for the fragment

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="8dp"
tools:context="org.gandroid.motif.Methods$PlaceholderFragment">

<WebView
    android:id="@+id/FPBriefsumm"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:background="@null"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:paddingBottom="2dp"
    />
```

and this is my java class for the fragment:

```
public class Methods_FamilyPlanning_brief extends Fragment {
TextView FPdesc,FPtitle;
WebView webView;
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_methods, container, false);

    webView = rootView.findViewById(R.id.FPBriefsumm);
    webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/familyplanning.html");
    webView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);

    WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    // Force links and redirects to open in the WebView instead of in a browser
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
```

I had tried all possible solutions from here:

1. [fragment-content-gets-cut-off](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36707624/fragment-content-gets-cut-off)
2. [android-listview-inside-fragment-gets-cut-off](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35120964/android-listview-inside-fragment-gets-cut-off/35121140#35121140)
3. [android-xml-cutting-off-bottom-half-of-layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35522317/android-xml-cutting-off-bottom-half-of-layout/35522468#35522468)
4. [android-studio-project-bottom-of-ui-is-cut-off](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33489430/android-studio-project-bottom-of-ui-is-cut-off)
   Still no luck :( 
   I tried it running on emulator and different physical devices but still the same. All I just wanna do is display a very long content in this fragment. Any idea would be great. Thanks in advance.

UPDATE :
I tried @Mahesh answer it now looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/40fWN.png). The last paragraph is missing.

My html code for the webview file.

```
<html>
```

**Family Planning**

Family planning is the practice of controlling the number of
        children in a family and the intervals between their births. Contemporary notions of family
        planning, however, tend to place a woman and her childbearing decisions at the center of the discussion,
        as notions of womens empowerment and reproductive autonomy have gained traction in many parts of the
        world. Family planning may involve consideration of the number of children a woman wishes to have,
        including the choice to have no children, as well as the age at which she wishes to have them.
        These matters are influenced by external factors such as marital situation, career considerations,
        financial position, any disabilities that may affect their ability to have children and raise them,
        besides many other considerations.

If sexually active, family planning may involve the use of contraception
        and other techniques to control the timing of reproduction. Other techniques commonly used include sexuality education,
        prevention and management of sexually transmitted infections,pre-conception counseling and management, and infertility management.

Family planning is sometimes used as a synonym or euphemism for access to and the use of contraception. However,
        it often involves methods and practices in addition to contraception. Additionally, there are many who might wish
        to use contraception but are not, necessarily, planning a family (e.g., unmarried adolescents, young married couples
        delaying childbearing while building a career); family planning has become a catch-all phrase for much of the work
        undertaken in this realm. It is most usually applied to a female-male couple who wish to limit the number of children
        they have and/or to control the timing of pregnancy (also known as spacing children).

Do you know when your last menstrual period began or how long it lasted? If not, it might be time to
        start paying attention.

Tracking your menstrual cycles can help you understand what's normal for you,
        time ovulation and identify important changes — such as a missed period or unpredictable menstrual bleeding.
        While menstrual cycle irregularities usually aren't serious, sometimes they can signal health problems.

**What's the menstrual cycle?**

The menstrual cycle is the monthly series of changes a woman's body goes through in preparation for the possibility of pregnancy.
        Each month, one of the ovaries releases an egg — a process called ovulation. At the same time, hormonal changes prepare
        the uterus for pregnancy. If ovulation takes place and the egg isn't fertilized, the lining of the uterus sheds through
        the vagina. This is a menstrual period.

**What's normal?**

The menstrual cycle, which is counted from the first
        day of one period to the first day of the next, isn't the same for every woman. Menstrual flow might occur every 21 to
        35 days and last two to seven days. For the first few years after menstruation begins, long cycles are common.
        However, menstrual cycles tend to shorten and become more regular as you age.

Your menstrual cycle might be regular — about the same length every month — or somewhat irregular, and your period might
        be light or heavy, painful or pain-free, long or short, and still be considered normal. Within a broad range, "normal"
        is what's normal for you.

Keep in mind that use of certain types of contraception, such as extended-cycle birth control pills and intrauterine
        devices (IUDs), will alter your menstrual cycle. Talk to your health care provider about what to expect.

When you get close to menopause, your cycle might become irregular again. However, because the risk of uterine
        cancer increases as you age, discuss any irregular bleeding around menopause with your health care provider.

```
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why you have given padding in webview remove that and try.

Comment: i just tried it based on the solutions given on some related thread it is still the same sir :(

Comment: Try changing the webview height to match_parent and not 0dp.  Setting to OverviewMode and WideViewPort will force resize the content might make it unreadable.

Answer (score 0):

```
Please try this.

webView .getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true); 
webView .getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
```

Comment: sir I still have one paragraph left

Comment: I tried deleting some of the <br> tags on my html file. the content is now unscrollable because the content is now smaller than the view size but the last paragraph is still missing. I don't have an idea what seems to be the problem. ill add a screenshot above sir

Comment: might be the issue in your html open that html in browser it is display correct or not ?

Comment: omg sir i just noticed that the content is complete. lol im sorry my bad. Thank you so much sir! Marked as answer.

Comment: sir 1 more thing, if i change the font size in my html file because it is too small it starts cutting off again the bottom contents.

Comment: is it scrolling ?